# Do not resolve view in RESTful Application

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I am building a web application with RESTful web services using Spring MVC 3. The web services will be used by applications, so should never really resolve any requests to a view. Is there any way to specify in the servlet context that no requests should resolve to any view?

At the moment, I have:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

which I know tries to resolve any request to a correspondingly named view in the `jsp` folder. However, if I remove this, the application just tries to use a default view resolver.

The reason I am concerned about this is that my application logs are going to be full of the following messages (even though it works fine):

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [/vouchd] threw exception [Circular view path [signup]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/vouchd/signup] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [signup]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/vouchd/signup] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

or with the `InternalViewResolver`:

```
WARN [http-bio-8080-exec-4] (DispatcherServlet.java:1057) - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/WEB-INF/jsp/call.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet'
```

which I guess is the better of the two evils. I don't want to turn off logging WARN level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with [`@ResponseStatus`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html). This code returns 204 with no content and view resolving skipped:

```
@ResponseStatus(NO_CONTENT)
void noView() {
  //...
}
```

If you want to return raw data and simply serialize it to JSON or XML, use [`@ResponseBody`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html):

```
@ResponseBody
MyPojo noView() {
  return new MyPojo();
}
```

Comment: I am still returning JSON data to the requesting application. Wouldn't this negate that?

Comment: @NicoHuysamen: sorry, I misunderstood *no requests should resovle to any view*, see my update.